# Is it possible to specifiy a port when connecting to host.docker.local on Docker Desktop For Mac?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to connect to a service running on the host machine from inside a container.

The container is connected to a custom network, here's the `docker network inspect` output,

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "acmenet",
        "Id": "3004da6e02752538a3103e46f785f6939761b6a5d196c85e86a4121a3c46af0e",
        "Created": "2023-07-19T22:17:31.845957625Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.30.50.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.30.50.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "8c5eace3018c29f7ab052546f7cbe7ce6fee2b1466eb98519ebb61017fab947c": {
                "Name": "pebble",
                "EndpointID": "94ff81a625ac52a74b63b9523ce600579abc6376244ac557c115cf6227a7f6d0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:1e:32:02",
                "IPv4Address": "10.30.50.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c9d33db1dddce49e3f0937ccdadf56a29b1985559fb79b217a15148a492b7bf1": {
                "Name": "pebble-challtestsrv",
                "EndpointID": "6b8cbd0e9bb05a28b274bd874f94cdf7aa2942b8cce76ae24385ce87c1f8c697",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:1e:32:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.30.50.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

From inside the container I can successfully ping addresses on the internet and can successfully ping `host.docker.internal`, but if I've specified a port I get connection refused errors.

For example, from inside the container `wget http://host.docker.local:5000` fails with connection refused.

Using Docker Desktop For Mac 4.21.1 (114176).

I read on a Docker community forum that differences on Docker For Mac make make this impossible.

Edit: Here is the output on the system console,

```
default 09:48:33.846358+1000    com.docker.backend  127.0.0.1:5000 <- 192.168.65.2:42454: dialing
default 09:48:33.846662+1000    com.docker.backend  127.0.0.1:5000 <- 192.168.65.2:42454: dial failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused
default 09:48:33.846515+1000    kernel  connect() - failed necp_set_socket_domain_attributes
```

Is it possible to specifiy a port when connecting to `host.docker.internal`?

Comment: "Is it possible to specifiy a port" -- it is **necessary** to specify a port; you can't establish a tcp connection without one! If you're getting a "connection refused" message, that suggests that there is in fact nothing listening on port 5000 on your host.

Comment: There is definitely something listening on port 5000.